# is replaceWith() duplicated with replaceAll()

Tags: jquery

I am learning jQuery,
get to know that some functions have liken function.
for example.
replaceWith() Vs. replaceAll().

according to their grammar defintion, just rotate the order of content and selected element.

similarily, append(), appendTo(), prepend(), prependTo(), after(), insertAfter(), before(), insertBefore().

I am newer in programming, can't really understand why there are many 'same' functions which have been put here for taking 'same' effect.

Then, why don't create just one or two (anyway, less, not many look like same) comprehensive and decent function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you're misleading with the documentation of JQuery.

Certains functions have the same effect, but can be called differently.

Let's take `replaceWith()` and `replaceAll()` for examples

The only difference is that you can put the replacement wether in the selector or the function's parameter.

JQuery is meant to be a toolbox that serves the most, and the most means that every programmers have different way to *behave* and they could appreciate more using a function that you find useless.
Furthermore, if those functions exists in two types, it's that it's a commonly wanted behavior of them for purposal of readability and/or usability within certains architectures.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hopefully, later on, I shall have further experience of their benefits with these different ways.